# Opacity feature for css - transparency inside div

Tags: css, html

I am confused abut the working of html `opacity` feature... Assume there are two `divs`, one inside the other, and I apply `opacity` to the outer div, it will automatically apply opacity to inner `div` too. how can we undo that, like opacity should work only for outer `div`?

Ive used the css code 
    opacity
http://jsfiddle.net/4uMdj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are using `background-color` in your outer DIV then you can define `rgba` value to it. Write like this:

```
.outer{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

& for IE use IE filter

you can generate your rgba filter for IE from here http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
}

.parent:before {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;

    opacity: 0.3;
    width: xxpx;
    height: xxpx;
    background: ; 
}

.child{
    Color:xx;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your just setting colours its easier and safer to use background opacity this will not effect any nested elements

```
.alpha
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use css, you can use rgba, but you have to override the background for child elements because otherwise it will be inherited from the parent div: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s3YYr/3/)

css from the example:

```
.opacity {
    background-color: rgba(0,150,0,0.2);
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.noopacity {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #090; /*non alpha background*/
    padding: 20px;
}
```

the most simple way to do it cross browser valid is to create a 1px PNG file in the color you need and with transparency and use the following css:

```
.opacity {
    background: url("path/to/your/1px/transparent/background/image.png");
}
```

because images won't get used as inherit background ;)

(note: IE6 does not support transparency on PNG by default!)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot undo (increase) the opacity on the nested element if you're using `opacity` applied on its parent element.

Try to use instead `background: rgba(r,g,b, opacity)` : this will not apply the opacity on nested elements